# Problem with iOS notifications in ReactNative

Tags: android, ios, react-native, notifications, pusher

We are looking for a problem in an application written in ReactNative. The case study related to the functionality that should display to refresh the icon badge in the application list. The icon is updated as a correlation with the messages received as a push notification. Notifications are sent via Pusher. The icon changes successfully on Android but not on iOS. What could be the reason? What is that different thing between the two systems that we can use to look for the cause of the problem.

We have tested various scenarios with all functionality other than messaging isolated and the only possibility that remains is an operating system issue. Maybe a permission, a certificate, or something that eludes us, like a setting.